# Win 8/64 Outlook 2007(Office 2007 Enterprise 64 bit)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I make a template as the default for just one of my email addresses? I want to ultimately make separate templates for all my email addresses.

Comment: Here is a video demo: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/demo-create-and-use-an-e-mail-template-HA010245004.aspx if you need something else be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your default message template in Outlook applies to all accounts in Outlook. Couple of workarounds I can think of are:

1. Create custom templates for each email account and access them via buttons in the toolbar.
2. Use a 3rd party Outlook template management software.